# How do i loop through a table and updating a specific column based on data in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

So i have two tables a ***users*** table and a ***user_roles*** table:

**users**
|   user_id   |  user_name  |
|:--------------|-----------------:|
|        1        |      userX      |
|        2        |      userY      |

**user_roles**
|  user_name  |   user_id   |
|:-----------------|---------------:|
|      userX       |   NULL     |
|      userY       |   NULL     |

I need to somehow loop through the ***user_roles*** table. For each *user_name* in ***user_roles*** that matches a *user_name* in ***users***, the specific user_id should be set instead of NULL in ***user_roles***.. How do i do this?

Note: user_name in users table is unique.

Comment: What do you expect to happen in user_roles table if someone adds or deletes a user_name from the users table?

Comment: Add UserZ to users table, and userW to user_roles table.

Comment: @jarlh I expect it to have the same effect in the user_roles table.. If a user is added it will also be added to user_roles and if it's deleted it would also be removed from user_roles.

Comment: Then you should create a view instead. Or use triggers to keep data consistent.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer will not fulfill that requirement. (Which should have been specified in the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For each `user_name` in `user_roles` that matches a `user_name` in `users`, the specific `user_id` should be set instead of `NULL` in `user_roles`

You could use a correlated subquery:

```
update user_roles r
set r.user_id = (
    select u.user_id from users u where u.user_name = r.user_name
)
```

This assumes that `user_name`s are unique in `users`. If not, then you would need some kind of aggregation or filtering so the subuquery returns just one record. For example, this will select the smalles `user_id` out of the matching `user_name`s:

```
update user_roles r
set r.user_id = (
    select min(u.user_id) from users u where u.user_name = r.user_name
)
```

---

In SQL Server the syntax is a bit different:

```
update r
set r.user_id = (select min(u.user_id) from users u where u.user_name = r.user_name)
from user_roles r
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can name a table in a set method? I get an error saying it expects "set" instead of "r".
BTW user_names are indeed unique in users table.

Comment: @YoussefBenarab: which RDMBS are you using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: That's valid ANSI SQL syntax, but perhaps not supported by all products.

Comment: I'm using SQL-server

Comment: @GMB Yep, that was it, i actually tried to do the same think but i see now that i failed because of the syntax. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome @YoussefBenarab! For your next question: please add the relevant database tag from the start; syntax does vary accross RDMBS...

Comment: @GMB Okay will do.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit better than using a subquery, but both are OK.

```
update r
set r.user_id = u.user_id
from user_roles r LEFT JOIN users u ON r.Username = u.Username
```